# Development gems being required in production, Phusion Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, bundler

I have a Phusion Passenger install, which is running in production mode (the default).  I've installed the appropriate gems on the server via:

```
rvmsudo bundle --without development test cucumber
```

When I restart Passenger, I get:

```
Error message:
    https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit.git (at master) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install` (Bundler::GitError)
```

capybara-webkit is defined in my gemfile as:

```
gem 'capybara-webkit', :git => 'https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit.git', :group => [:cucumber, :test, :development]
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the --deployment switch solved the issue (no need to rvmsudo either):

bundle --without development test cucumber --deployment